# How to make rect.intersects just check outside boundaries

Tags: java, user-interface, intersection

I am trying to determine if clickRectangle, a rectangle created by the click of a mouse, on a canvas intersects with a drawnRectangle or not.

However, I don't want the intersects method to return true if I click anywhere in the drawnRectangle (i.e. the interior of the rectangle), I just want it to return true if an outer boundary of drawnRectangle was clicked.

How can I do that?

P.S: For clickRectangle and drawnRectangle see my comment below.

Comment: A rectangle should take 2 clicks. How are you making it with only 1?

Comment: what I mean is I create a rectangle from the click of a mouse by centering it and internally creating an invisible rectangle to check if an actual drawn rectangle intersects with it or not.. I realized the lack of distinct names for rectangles might have caused a confusion so here is and update.. clickRectangle refers to the rectangle that is created by the click of the mouse.. drawnRectangle refers to the actual rectangle that I try to check for intersection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want

```
public static boolean pointNearEdge(Point click, Rectangle drawnRectangle, int howNear){
   Rectangle clickRect = new Rectangle(click.x-howNear, click.y-howNear, howNear*2, howNear*2);
   if (drawnRectangle.contains(clickRect))  // totally inside -> false
      return false;

   // test if there is a partial intersection - i.e. we are near the edge
   return drawnRectangle.intersects(clickRect);
}
```

Comment: this really helped thanks.. after I integrated to my code, turns out all I need was the contains method. Thanks again tho. Great help.